# Error sql syntax in update query

Tags: php, mysql

i have this query which i use in order to update a table, the issue is i ge this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'emri='Albana', klienti='Distribrands', telefoni='0662080090', montim='Kompjut' at line 1
```

I can't find the error here.. it's strange...
Please help me with this.
It's an update query!
The query :

```
$sqlStart="UPDATE forma SET ";
$sql="";
if ($postDyqani_pergjegjes!= 'undefined') $sql .= " dyqani_pergjegjes='$postDyqani_pergjegjes',";
if ($postEmri!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  emri='$postEmri',";
if ($postKlienti!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  klienti='$postKlienti',";
if ($postTelefoni!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  telefoni='$postTelefoni',";
if ($postMontim!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  montim='$postMontim',";
if ($postAdresa!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  adresa='$postAdresa',";
if ($postData_e_shitjes!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  data_e_shitjes='$postData_e_shitjes',";
if ($postDifekti!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  difekti='$postDifekti',";
if ($postTekniku_emer!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  tekniku_emer='$postTekniku_emer',";
if ($postTekniku_mesazh!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  tekniku_mesazh='$postTekniku_mesazh',";
if ($postData_fillim!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  data_fillim='$postData_fillim',";
if ($postData_mbarim!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  data_mbarim='$postData_mbarim',";
if ($postData!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  data='$postData',";
if ($postStatus!= 'undefined') $sql .= "  status='$postStatus',";
// replace the last `,` for `;`
if ($sql != "") {
    // replace the last `,` for `;`
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1) . ";";
    // run sql command
    $sqlCommand = $sqlStart.$sql;
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()) ;

} else {
    // no fields to update
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So we are supposed to guess what is your update query?

Comment: No, i just can't find the error.. let me write the query here..

Comment: Please provide us your code......at least query..

Comment: Can You print the query on screen?

Comment: actually you got more than one error there

Comment: Make sure you are escaping apostrophes in your strings

Comment: Could you please tell me which is my error here.. thanks!

Comment: and you should learn about prepared statement too. Your code suffers injection.

Comment: Stating the obvious: SQL errors are caused by SQL code and triggered by the MySQL server. Don't start debugging from the PHP side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are executing `$sql` which is only half of the query. The full query is in `$sqlCommand` so execute that:

```
 $result=mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Side notes: you should ensure that the variables are escaped for single quotes (see `mysql_real_escape_string()`). The `mysql_*` library is deprecated, so it is recommended to migrate to PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

Please write $sqlCommand in place of $sql as the final  query is in this variable.